# WillRestoreState not called when app killed by the system

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, ios-bluetooth, state-restoration

Im trying to create an application which connects to a BP cuff. I want to enable state restoration in the app so that even if the app is killed by the system the app can still be invoked when the BP cuff is available and transmitting. Here are some of the things I have tried so far.

1) Adding a resource identifier to centralManager init and assigning a background serial queue to it

```
var ble_dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.xyz.ios.ble")
        let opts = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey : true,    CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:
            "ios.xyz.ble.peripheral.identifier"] as [String : Any]

        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate : self, queue : ble_dispatchQueue, options : opts)
```

2) implementing willRestoreState and centralManagerDidUpdateState

```
   func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {

    print("will restore state called")
    if let peripheralsObject = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] {
        // 2
        let peripherals = peripheralsObject as! Array<CBPeripheral>
        // 3
        if peripherals.count > 0 {
            // 4
            self.peripheralDevice = peripherals[0]
            // 5
            self.peripheralDevice?.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

centralManagerDidUpdateState :

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    if central.state != .poweredOn {
        self.peripheralDevice = nil
        return
    }
    startScan()

    // 1

    guard let peripheral = self.peripheralDevice else {
        return
    }
    // 2
    guard peripheral.state == .connected else {
        return
    }
    // 3
    guard let peripheralServices = peripheral.services else {
        return
    }
    // 4
    serviceUUID = deviceParameters.deviceTypeUUIDs![0]

    if let serviceIndex = peripheralServices.index(where: {$0.uuid == serviceUUID}) {
        let ANDService = peripheralServices[serviceIndex]
        let characteristicUUIDs = deviceParameters.deviceCharacteristicUUIDs
        if let cUUIDs = characteristicUUIDs, let characteristics = ANDService.characteristics {
            // 6
            for i in 0..<cUUIDs.count {
                if let characteristicIndex = characteristics.index(where : {$0.uuid == cUUIDs[i]}) {
                    let characteristic = characteristics[characteristicIndex]
                    // 7
                    if !characteristic.isNotifying {
                        peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                    } else {
                        peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    }
                } else {
                    // 8
                    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(characteristicUUIDs, for: ANDService)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // 5
        peripheral.discoverServices([serviceUUID])
    }

}
```

The way Im trying to test it is by calling :-

```
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
```

to simulate process killing by the system. I'm not fiddling with bluetooth state / airplane mode or phone reboot.
Im initializing my centralManager inside didLaunchWithOptions
I have breakpoints at didLaunchWithOptions which gets called everytime the BP cuff is ready to connect and at willRestoreState which never gets called.

Can someone please suggest what else I can do to invoke willRestoreState?

Comment: Are you instantiating your CBCentralManager with a restoration ID?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a restoration id to your `CBCentralManager` or the delegate method is never called.

```
let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "my-central"]
self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
```

Once you've done that `willRestoreState` is always called when the `CBCentralManager` is instantiated.

Also, make sure you have `UIBackgroundModes` (Array) with 'bluetooth-central' as an item in your Info.plist.